# Partial matching a word in python

Tags: match, partial

I'm trying to write an auto-complete program in python that takes a (possibly misspelled) word and finds possible partial matches for it against a dictionary. Specifically, I am looking for words with one more, one less, or one different character. Is there a way to do this in python without writing a regex string generator based on the input word? Like, can I write three general regex strings, or do I have to write a function to create and test separate regex strings with a wildcard in every place in the word?

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a programming exercise, or are you interested in doing actual spelling correction and autocompletion?  I ask because your "words with one more, one less, or one different" technique is not necessarily how these kinds of things actually work in practice.

Comment: But just for curiosity's sake, how would one go about actually writing a spelling correction function?

Comment: [Peter Norvig shows you how here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) :)